# how to import angular2 ng2-bootstrap with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-bootstrap

i want to import the ng2-bootstrap into my angular2 written in pure javascript not typescript,
i cant find any resource for doing it,any one can help me with a sample?

also ive added the reference to ng2-bootstrap.js file in html document

app.AppMod

```
ule =
  ng.core.NgModule({
      imports: [ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule,
                ng.forms.FormsModule,
                ng2Bootstrap.Ng2BootstrapModule], // **this is the way id import it**
      declarations: [app.AppComponent],          
      bootstrap: [app.AppComponent]
  })
  .Class({
      constructor: function () { }
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: Did you try this way? - `var ng2_bootstrap = require('ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap');`

Comment: no but im not sure if this approach works